# TYPO3 – DCE extension: Get uids of current DCE instance and of section instance

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I am using Dynamic Content Elements (dce) in TYPO3 6.2 to build a Twitter Bootstrap accordion element.
To do so, I built an accordion DCE with a section element that stores all the accordion items.

Now Bootstrap requires that I have a means of referencing the overall accordion instance from within each accordion item. (This is needed because there could be multiple accordions on the same page.)

I found a way of doing that using {contentObject.uid}. This gives me the TYPO3 content element uid of the DCE, which is unique. It would be nicer to have some counter starting at 1 in each page. I guess, DCE holds something like that, but I have now clue how to access it.

The real problem is that I also need a unique id for each accordion item within the overall accordion. There should be some section element uid in DCE, but again, I have now clue how it is named and how I can access it from the fluid template.

Here is my current DCE fluid template:

```
{namespace dce=Tx_Dce_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_{contentObject.uid}">
        <f:for each="{field.accelement}" as="accordion-element">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{contentObject.uid}" data-target="#collapse_{accordion-element.uid}">{accordion-element.elheadline}</button>
                <div id="collapse_{accordion-element.uid}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {accordion-element.elcontent}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </div>
</f:section>
```

The element that is not working is {accordion-element.uid}. I tried anything from {accordion-element.id} to {field.accelement.id} and {field.accelement.uid} – but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well – as usual: 
After having a break I immediately saw the solution that I could not find for two hours before.

Adding a *key* property to the for-each-loop does the magic.

```
{namespace dce=Tx_Dce_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_{contentObject.uid}">
        <f:for each="{field.accelement}" key="n" as="accordion-element">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{contentObject.uid}" data-target="#collapse_{contentObject.uid}_{n}">{accordion-element.elheadline}</button>
                <div id="collapse_{contentObject.uid}_{n}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {accordion-element.elcontent}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </div>
</f:section>
```

To ensure that all accordion items are unique even if multiple accordions are placed on the same page, we have to use *contentObject.uid* AND the current loop key together: `collapse_{contentObject.uid}_{n}`